# How to make a template already used re-appear in the HTML

Tags: javascript, html, templates

So I'm trying to reset it after it disappears from the screen with a button. I tried a document.write() but it doesn't work, So I try that after being used, to rewrite my template argue in my HTML so I can use it again with other datas. Is that even possible?
This is my HTML:

```html
<template id="playlist__screen">
  <button class="backbutton" onclick="onClick()"></button>
  <p class="playlist__type">{{style}}</p>
  <h2 class='playlist__titre'>{{titre}}</h2>
  <p class="playlist__desc">{{description}}</p>
</template>
```

Comment: You cannot use document.write after load.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] suing the `[<>]` snippet editor. It is not clear what you are trying to do here

Comment: So I try after being used, to rewrite my template argue in my HTML so I can use it again with other datas

Comment: Show what you did - you are now just repeating what you already said. What is expected output and why don’t you have both versions in the template and hide what you are not needing?

Comment: I need with javascript to after used this template and when clicking the button, the template to get back in the HTML like the HTML I show. I want after him being used to get reset to it original form on the HTML, to be reused with other datas. I can't show more, it's all here.

Comment: The template does not disappear- you clone it and change it

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you use a template

```js
const plays = [{
    "style": "Style 1",
    "titre": "Titre 1",
    "description": "Description 1"
  },
  {
    "style": "Style 2",
    "titre": "Titre 2",
    "description": "Description 2"
  },
  {
    "style": "Style 3",
    "titre": "Titre 3",
    "description": "Description 3"
  }
];
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const template = document.getElementById("template"),
    content = document.getElementById("content");
  plays.forEach(play => {
    const playList = template.content.cloneNode(true);
    playList.querySelector(".playlist__type").textContent = play.style;
    playList.querySelector(".playlist__titre").textContent = play.Titre;
    playList.querySelector(".playlist__desc").textContent = play.description;
    content.appendChild(playList);
  })
  content.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains("backbutton")) {
      console.log("back clicked");
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
<template id="template"> 
  <div class="playlist__screen">
    <button class="backbutton">Back</button>
    <p class="playlist__type"></p>
    <h2 class="playlist__titre"></h2>
    <p class="playlist__desc"></p>
  </div>
</template>
```